# What is the best guide to learn XML

Tags: xml

I'm learning XML, currently of Wikibooks, but that is kinda huge and not oversee-able...

anybody know a better place?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp) are generally good for this type of stuff.

Comment: Good site. NOTE the test application at http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog has a hard limit of 5023 characters XML (blank output at 5024 with no warning/error.)

Comment: or maybe they aren't. see http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for a book, [O'Reilly](http://oreilly.com/) has a few [XML book](http://xml.oreilly.com/)s. Since I had picked up XML on the job, I just went with [XML in a Nutshell](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596007645/index.html) for use as a reference. You might be able to use them to find a good tutorial book on XML for a beginner like [Learning XML](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596004200/index.html), if that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I found Tim Bray's [Annotated XML Specification](http://www.xml.com/axml/testaxml.htm) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are building web applications without the need for JavaScript, but if you are I have found the wikibooks very helpful:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XQuery
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XForms

The XQuery book uses the eXist-db.org XML database which I have found to be a great learning tool.

- Dan

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your background and what you already know.

I found this a useful book though: http://www.ineasysteps.com/books/details/?1840781246

Answer (score 0):

zvon.org has good tutorials on many xml technologies

Answer (score -1):

Even though there are plenty of tutorials about XML , I agree with Galwegian . I learned XML from [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp).

Answer (score -1):

I think www.w3schools.com is a really good place to start learning XML